# How return statement work in nodes

Tags: node.js, express

I am newbie in ExpressJs and I do not clear about return statement of middleware. Please see below code :-

### middleware.js

```
exports.checkPrivilege = (stateName, forPrivilege) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {  // THIS LINE MAKE CONFUSE, i.e, req, res and next

    }
}
```

### module.js

```
.....
.....
router.post('/create', checkPrivilege('module', 'write'), (req, res, next) => {

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that `checkPrivilege()` is a function that, when called returns another function.  In this case, it returns a function that  is of the right format to use as a middleware handler.

So, when `checkPrivilege(x,y)` is called, it returns another function (that has not been executed yet) that can then be used as middleware.

So, when you see this:

```
router.post('/create', checkPrivilege('module', 'write'), (req, res, next) => {
    // code here
    next();
});
```

This does the following steps:

1. Creates a POST route handler for the `/create` route.
2. Calls `checkPrivilege('module', 'write')` immediately and as the return value it gets back another function that becomes a middleware handler for the `/create` route.
3. Then defines an inline anonymous route handler function for the `/create` route that will run after the middleware handler is done.

For a bit of clarity, it could also be written:

```
// create middleware function
let checkPrivilegeMiddleware1 = checkPrivilege('module', 'write');

// create route handler with middleware
router.post('/create', checkPrivilegeMiddleware1, (req, res, next) => {
    // code here
    next();
});
```

The typical reason it's done this way is that it is an easy way to make some parameters `stateName` and `forPrivilege` available to the middleware without creating another inline function body.  This way the `checkPrivilege()` function can be used in multiple places within your code, each with their own `stateName` and `forPrivilege` settings - thus more reusable.